# Python zipfile crashes gives an error for some files

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have a simple code to zip files using `zipfile` module. I am able to zip some files but I get `FileNotFound` error for the others. I have checked if this is file size error but its not.

I can pack files with name like `example file.py` but when I have a file inside a directory like 'Analyze Files en-US_es-ES.xlsx' if fails.

It works when I change `os.path.basename` to `os.path.join` but **I don't want to zip whole folder structure, I want to have flat structure in my zip.**

Here is my code:

```
import os
import zipfile

path = input()

x=zipfile.ZipFile('new.zip', 'w')
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
    for eachFile in files:        
        x.write(os.path.basename(eachFile))
x.close()
```

Error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/Zip test.py", line 15, in <module>    
x.write(os.path.basename(eachFile))  
File "C:\Python34\lib\zipfile.py", line 1326, in write    
st = os.stat(filename)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Analyze Files en-US_ar-SA.xlsx'*
```

Comment: What is the value of `path`? How is `ZipFile` to know where `Analyze Files en-US_ar-SA.xlsx` is on your system?

Comment: If you are on windows remember to use the 'wb' etc to open the file if it is binary

Comment: path is give by user for ex 

'd:\TEMP\__Working area\Project Packages\'

Comment: I cant use 'wb' while creating a zip it can be only 'w' 'r' 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Simply change working directory to add file without original directory structure.

```
import os
import zipfile

path = input()

baseDir = os.getcwd()
with zipfile.ZipFile('new.zip', 'w') as z:
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
        os.chdir(root)
        for eachFile in files:
            z.write(eachFile)
        os.chdir(baseDir)
```

Comment: thanks for help I have use path.basename instead because I dont want whole folder structure.

Comment: @MaciejPL  My bad, I copy-pasted it form my previous resoponse, where I misunderstood a problem. In your case `os.path.basename(eachFile)` would be equal to `eachFile` anyway. Please read [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'm just confused about this dir changing parts. Could you please tell me what happens here. Really appriciate.